# Gremlin : How to use a linked vertex in a filter closure?

Tags: neo4j, gremlin

I have a linked list of activities for a user, like this :

```
(user)-ACTIVITIES->(activity)-NEXT*->(activity)->...
```

Each activity node is related to a source node and a target node

```
(theSource)<-SOURCE-(activity)-TARGET->(theTarget)
```

I want to retrieve all activities, with a filter on the source. How can I filter with a source node ? I Want to filter activities, where source.email = 'someone@email.com'. This code does not work :/

```
g.v(1).out('ACTIVITIES')
.as('x')
.out('NEXT')
.loop('x'){it.loops <= 10}{true}
.filter{
    it.out('SOURCE').email == 'someone@email.com'
}
```

How can I filter with a linked node in the filter closure ? Is this a good way to do that ?

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to next() your pipeline in the filter.  It should be:

```
.filter{
    it.out('SOURCE').email.next() == 'someone@email.com'
}
```

Without the `next` you are doing an equality on a Pipeline which will never return true.

As an added suggestion I would recommend you change your emit closure (the second one) on the loop.  The emit closure controls the items that escape the pipe.  By setting to `true` as you have it now it is emitting everything and then you are applying the filter.  A bit more compact way to do it would be to make your traversal look like this:

```
g.v(1).out('ACTIVITIES')
.as('x')
.out('NEXT')
.loop('x'){it.loops <= 10}{it.out('SOURCE').email.next() == 'someone@email.com'}
```

In this way you handle the filtering in the emit closure as opposed to a separate step of the pipeline.

Comment: Thank you it works! I think I need to read more about pipes, it's not very easy to understand :) Thank you also about your tips on emit a closure :)

Comment: Almost everything in Gremlin evals to a pipeline.  You have to `next()` /`iterate()`more often than not.  You can read more about it here: http://gremlindocs.com/#methods/pipe-iterate and http://gremlindocs.com/#methods/pipe-next